# How to fix in transform NSAttributedString from html string in swift?

Tags: html, ios, swift, iphone, nsattributedstring

When I convert html string to NSAttributedString, it works well normally but I have a problem in specific cases.

```
func htmlAttributed(family: String?, size: CGFloat, color: UIColor) -> NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            let htmlCSSString = "<style>" +
                "html *" +
                "{" +
                "font-size: \(size)px;" +
                "color: \(color.hex);" +
                "font-family: \(family ?? "Helvetica"), Helvetica;" +
            "}</style> \(self)"

            guard let data = htmlCSSString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
                return nil
            }

            return try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                          options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

This is my test case html string which has problem.
`<b>Hi <i>how are <u>you?</u></i></b>`

And it's my result with NSAttributedString.
**Hi** *how are you?*

I wanted to get all bold in this sentence but I got only `Hi` bold string.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Test case html]

Seems to work. Color was changed to a `String` type for this quick test. Your function was included in a `String` extension. The following is the call to the function. Returned attributed string was converted to data, in MS Word format, resulting in the above final sentence, displayed in Word.

```
var s = "<b>Hi <i>how are <u>you?</u></i></b>"
var attr = s.htmlAttributed(family: nil, size: 20, color: "blue")

var MWdata = attr!.docFormat(from: NSRange(location: 0, length: attr!.length),documentAttributes: [NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey(rawValue: "documentType"):NSAttributedString.DocumentType.docFormat])
```

Comment: `NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey(rawValue: "documenType")` ??? It's missing a "t", and why not use the key?

Comment: Fixed the missing 't'. As the MWdata line was unrelated to the initial question about the code, I did not take the time to figure out exactly how to use the docFormat() method. I was just entering text on the fly, with assistance from the Xcode editor, using this unfamiliar method.

Comment: Question is why do `NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey(rawValue: "documentType")` when you should do `NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.documentType`? What if Apple change the rawValue in next version?